# mysql 1093 error subselect work-around improvement

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

The following UPDATE query works fine:

```
UPDATE product SET gcode = '9a8a'
WHERE gcode = '81cd'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM
    (SELECT 1 FROM product WHERE gcode = '9a8a') AS x
)
```

But uses an extra nested select to work-around the MySQL error:

```
1093: You can't specify target table 'product' for update in FROM clause
```

Is there a way to improve this query in this particular situation?

This query just updates all records with a field of the specified value with a new value. But I don't want to update if their are already records with the new value. It seems this is probably a common situation.

Comment: maybe because of 1? what is that?

Comment: I don't see how you get that error when the tables in the subquery and update are different

Comment: it's either you're not showing the full sql for some reason or it is something other than SQL. The SQl seems fine without the nested `select 1 from`.

Comment: @FuzzyTree - table name supposed to be the same. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine without the nested select:

```
UPDATE product
    SET gcode = '9a8a'
    WHERE gcode = '81cd' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trans WHERE trans_gcode = '9a8a');
```

The double nesting is only needed when the subquery references the table being updated.

EDIT:

Well, your edit makes a small difference.  You can do this with a `left outer join`:

```
UPDATE product p LEFT OUTER JOIN
       trans t
       on trans_gcode = '9a8a'
    SET gcode = '9a8a'
    WHERE gcode = '81cd' AND t.trans_gcode is NULL;
```

Comment: Sorry, the table name 'trans' was a typo, should have been 'product'. Fixed it in my original question. In MySQL, selecting from same table while updating is not supported and produces 1093 error. The extra subselect is a work-around.